# Improved Gradient Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, vector-analysis, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Show that asymptotic stability of the adaptation error is assured for $0<\gamma<2, \alpha>0$.

$$
\hat{\theta}(t + 1) = \hat{\theta}(t) + \frac{\gamma \phi(t)\varepsilon^{0}(t + 1)}{\alpha + \phi^T(t)\phi(t)}
$$

Any ideas? Would someone give me some references link?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide more context?

Comment: What is $\varphi$, $\varepsilon$?

Comment: This is about parameter adaptation algorithm an improved gradient algoritm